# Is Tale of Fairy Ice Trail Considered Canon?

Tags: fairy-tail

Well, is that manga considered canon? I heard that Hiro Mashima praised it as being very good, but does he also accepts it as canon?

Edit: The Key of the Starry Sky arc are not in the manga, yet Mashima-sensei considered it as canon. So, considering this fact, does Hiro Mashima consider this series as a canon as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, I've searched Fairy Tail Wiki and found this:

> Tale of Fairy Tail: Ice Trail (氷の軌跡, アイストレイル, Aisu Toreiru) is a Japanese manga series by Yusuke Shirato and a spin-off of Hiro Mashima's manga series Fairy Tail.

If it's a spin-off I don't think it's canon

Comment: that it's a spin-off doesn't mean it's not canon, there have been a lot of spin-offs of series which are canon. "In media, a spin-off is a radio program, television program, video game, film, or any narrative work, derived from one or more already existing works, that focuses, in particular, in more detail on one aspect of that original work (e.g. a particular topic, character, or event). A spin-off may be called a sidequel when it exists in the same chronological frame of time as its predecessor work"

Comment: Indeed, Fairy Tail Zero is an example of a spin-off which is definitely canon. So the term "spin-off" does not imply non-canon.